# Settings StringCollection: NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, stringcollection

I would like to store some data from a list<.string> in a Settings.StringCollection (System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection), but everytime I try to add the data to the collection, I get an Exception for this code:

```
Settings.Default.fav01.Add(favArray[i]);
```

Error:

```
NullReference Exception was unhandled

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So, how do I fix this (or set that mentioned reference)?

Comment: if you did not add something to `fav` in the settings editor, it will start out null.

Comment: `if(Settings.Default.fav01 == null) Settings.Default.fav01 = new DERP();`

Comment: of note is that the "VB Answer" on that link covers this specifically (in the last topical section)

Comment: Thanks, but I do understand what a NullReferenceException is, it's just confusing that I actually have to add a value to the StringCollection in the Settings-(GUI)-page, since this is not required for normal strings.

Comment: the IDE doesnt initialize the collection unless there is something in it; if you dont add something via the Settings Editor it starts out null (as explained in the linked answer).